# Building a TikZ-matrix from specific data

Tags: tikz-pgf, matrices

If I have a table like

```
1 | 3 | s   1 | 1 | r
5 | 3 | b   11 | 3 | b
3 | 1 | r   19 | 3 | s
```

(*this is an example, there could be more columns or rows*), where each cell contains 3 pieces of information: `<denominator>|<numerator>|<color>`.

`<color>`: r = red, b = blue, s = standard (black).

How can I put this into a TikZ-matrix applying the information?

[image]

*Because in TikZ, there are manifold possibilities for visualization, for example:*

[image]

Left: possible visualization for a quite big table. Right: Another visualization

**MWE:**

```
%\documentclass[11pt, landscape]{scrartcl}
\documentclass[border=3mm, varwidth]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz, amsmath, amssymb}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}  

\begin{document}

IS:  
\begin{verbatim}
1 | 3 | s               1 | 1 | r
5 | 3 | b              11 | 3 | b
3 | 1 | r              19 | 3 | s
\end{verbatim}

SHALL: \\
\begin{tikzpicture}
\matrix (m) [       
ampersand replacement=\&,
matrix of math nodes, 
nodes in empty cells,
]
{%
\frac13 \& |[text=red]|1 \\
|[text=blue]|\frac53 \& |[text=blue]|\frac{11}{3} \\
|[text=red]|3  \&  \frac{19}{3} \\
};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)

Comment: Please explain the rule for combining the information in the rows. Perhaps it is the obvious one but it would be good to know - although the colouring is not obvious to me. Are r, b and s tne only labels dor the rows? It would be easier/betterI think if there was a `|` between the third and fourth columns. Finally, `Tikz ` does not seem to be necessary from the MWE. Is there some unstated reason as to why it should be used rather than, for example, just a `tabular` environment?

Comment: Done. ...................

Comment: Please don't put regular text explaining things into code format - screen readers have to read it to users character by character. 'Left: possible visualization for a quite big table. Right: Another visualization' would be easier read as words, don't you think?

Comment: I don't understand the 'Left: possible visualization for a quite big table. Right: Another visualization' comment, though. What is the left bit and what the right bit? And how are they equivalent? And how is that related to what you're trying to do?

Comment: This was an answer of the question from @Andrew, why I am looking for a TikZ solution.

Comment: Are you aware that Ti*k*Z is s-s-s-l-l-l-o-o-o-o-o-o-w-w-w? When you use it to do maths, it gets really gummy, really fast. I guess you are going to preprocess somehow anyway, but doing it outside TeX altogether would probably be easiest.

Comment: Yes, I wrote a Mathematica-programm to build the data-tables. Doing it all inside TeX ist not bad, but the rows are proportional to 2^n and integer functions are needed. That means, pgfmath will run out, if n is big enough. I tried it and so I do not think, calculating all with TeX is a good idea.

Comment: Why not having a simple 3-entry CSV file? Then it is quite straigtforward via `pgfplotstable`. You can also break into columns etc. What you have is a very peculiar table format with nontrivial parsing

Comment: Crosspost in German: http://texwelt.de/wissen/fragen/21232/tikz-matrix-aus-speziellem-datensatz-erstellen

Comment: @ percusse  I think you are right. I will explore in this direction ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because this question received quite some attention, I'll crosspost my answer to the German version on TeXwelt:

> [Tikz-Matrix aus speziellem Datensatz erstellen](http://texwelt.de/wissen/fragen/21232/tikz-matrix-aus-speziellem-datensatz-erstellen)

---

Using [`lpeg`](http://www.inf.puc-rio.br/~roberto/lpeg/) you can parse arbitrary data formats.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{luacode}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\colorlet{s}{black}
\colorlet{b}{blue}
\colorlet{r}{red}

\begin{luacode*}
local lpeg = assert(require"lpeg")
local C, P, R, S = lpeg.C, lpeg.P, lpeg.R, lpeg.S

local space = S(" \t")^0
local line = S("\n\r")^0

local integer = space * R("09")^1 / tonumber
local sep = space * P("|")
local color = space * C(R("az"))

local function col(num, denom, color)
   if (denom == 1) then
      tex.sprint(string.format("\\textcolor{%s}{$%d$}",color,num))
   else
      tex.sprint(string.format("\\textcolor{%s}{$\\frac{%d}{%d}$}",color,num,denom))
   end
end

local function row()
   tex.sprint("\\medbreak")
end

local entry = ((integer * sep * integer * sep * color / col)^1 * line / row)^1

function parse(tab)
   entry:match(tab)
end
\end{luacode*}

\begin{document}

\begin{luacode*}
parse[[
1 | 3 | s               1 | 1 | r
5 | 3 | b              11 | 3 | b
3 | 1 | r              19 | 3 | s
]]
\end{luacode*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Putting everything in a table is left as an exercise.  In ConTeXt this is of course much easier...

```
\definecolor[s][black]
\definecolor[b][blue]
\definecolor[r][red]

\startluacode
local lpeg = assert(require"lpeg")
local C, P, R, S = lpeg.C, lpeg.P, lpeg.R, lpeg.S

local space = S(" \t")^0
local line = S("\n\r")^0

local integer = space * R("09")^1 / tonumber
local sep = space * P("|")
local color = space * C(R("az"))

local function col(num, denom, color)
   if (denom == 1) then
      context.NC(string.format("\\color[%s]{$%d$}",color,num))
   else
      context.NC(string.format("\\color[%s]{$\\frac{%d}{%d}$}",color,num,denom))
   end
end

local function row()
   context.NC()
   context.NR()
end

local entry = ((integer * sep * integer * sep * color / col)^1 * line / row)^1

function parse(tab)
   context.startTABLE{ frame="off", align="middle,lohi" }
   entry:match(tab)
   context.stopTABLE()
end
\stopluacode

\starttext

\startluacode
parse[[
1 | 3 | s               1 | 1 | r
5 | 3 | b              11 | 3 | b
3 | 1 | r              19 | 3 | s
]]
\stopluacode

\stoptext
```

[image]